# Compare and Sort a Column in Excel

Tags: excel, sorting, compare

I am a firefighter and when we have large wildfires in California we order a lot of overhead positions to assist at the fire.  These overhead position fall into 1 of 6 categories.

As I import the list of outstanding overhead requests into Excel, is there I way I can assign a value to each position?  1 through 6?  I can then sort the entire list by number and hand a list of all "1's" to one person and "2's" to another person etc.

I'd like to assign a value to each position COMPARED to a master list.  On the master list I will tell Excel that a "Helicopter Coordinator" = 1 for example.

Thanks for the assistance :)

Here's an example of some miscellaneous overhead positions:

O-42    OPERATIONS BRANCH DIRECTOR (OPBD)

O-44    TECHNICAL SPECIALIST - CREWS (CALIFORNIA ONLY)

O-45    INCINET STATUS/CHECK-IN RECORDER (CALIFORNIA ONLY)

O-47    OPERATIONS BRANCH DIRECTOR (OPBD)

O-48    FIRE FIGHTER TYPE 2 (FFT2)

O-50    HELICOPTER COORDINATOR (HLCO)

O-52    MEDICAL UNIT LEADER (MEDL)

Comment: there are a few different Excel functions that can do this. What have you tried already, and what are you having difficulty with? And how are you importing the data, is it with VBA, using a database query, lookup formulas?

Comment: I haven't really tried anything yet... I'm pretty certain that it can be done, just not sure how to do it...

Comment: We use a Resource Ordering program called ROSS... I export the pending requests from there and into an Excel spreadsheet

Comment: Essentially I want to say that IF B2 equals anything on list 1 THEN put a 1 in the box.  IF B2 equals anything on list 2 THEN put a 2 in the box, etc...

Comment: VLOOKUP or INDEX with MATCH would do it.

Comment: You create a reference table which maps all the overhead positions to the 6 categories. The position goes on the left column and category on the right. Then in the export sheet you  add a column and you VLOOKUP the overhead position, in your extract data, against your reference table and retrieve the second column value.  How it works [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/vlookup-function-0bbc8083-26fe-4963-8ab8-93a18ad188a1) and some SO VLookup questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=vba+vlookup)